# How to merge certain lines in a textfile in python

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'd like to turn this textfile:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

I tried implementing something like this:

```
for n,line in enumerate(data):
if line.startswith("video"):
   data[n] = "\n"+line.rstrip()
else:
   data[n]=line.rstrip()
```

I eventually would like to make this textfile into a pandas dataframe, do you think it would be easier to make the file a dataframe and then manipulate it? Any guidance/help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Sorry I', having trouble trying to format the text but here it is in raw form:

```
video 1/1 (1/742) ( 20 214 34 252 ) 
( 249 205 275 246 ) 
( 256 128 396 224 ) Done.
video 1/1 (2/742) ( 248 202 276 246 ) 
( 244 152 341 238 ) ( 20 214 34 252 ) 
( 254 129 397 224 ) Done. 
video 1/1 (3/742) ( 246 152 341 238 ) 
( 248 202 277 247 ) 
( 20 214 34 252 ) 
( 255 129 396 224 )  Done. 
video 1/1 (4/742) ( 248 202 277 247 ) 
( 245 152 341 238 ) 
( 20 214 34 252 ) 
( 255 129 396 224 )  Done. 
video 1/1 (5/742) ( 17 213 36 251 ) 
( 246 153 339 238 ) 
( 252 203 278 247 ) 
( 254 129 398 223 )  Done.
```

Comment: please post the data as text, thank you

Comment: Sorry about that! I have edited the post.

Comment: what you have done so far is quite good, but i would actually build strings until reaching `Data.` as that is when a sentance is completed.

Comment: What do you mean by "build strings"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a combination of [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and logical conditions to create a list of lists that we can then feed in to a DataFrame.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

pattern = re.compile(r"video [0-9]/[0-9] \([0-9/[0-9]+\)")

final = []
with open("foo.txt", "r") as fin:
    out = []
    for line in fin:
        # check to see if regex matches and if there is data to append
        if pattern.search(line) and len(out) > 0:
            final.append(out)
            out = []
        out.append(line.strip())
# append the final group
final.append(out)

pd.DataFrame(final)

                                       0  ...                           3
0    video 1/1 (1/742) ( 20 214 34 252 )  ...                        None
1  video 1/1 (2/742) ( 248 202 276 246 )  ...                        None
2  video 1/1 (3/742) ( 246 152 341 238 )  ...  ( 255 129 396 224 )  Done.
3  video 1/1 (4/742) ( 248 202 277 247 )  ...  ( 255 129 396 224 )  Done.
4    video 1/1 (5/742) ( 17 213 36 251 )  ...  ( 254 129 398 223 )  Done.

[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is a list of strings, solution is given below

```
data = [
    "video 1/1 (1/742) ( 20 214 34 252 ) ",
    "( 249 205 275 246 ) ",
    "( 256 128 396 224 ) Done.",
    "video 1/1 (2/742) ( 248 202 276 246 ) ",
    "( 244 152 341 238 ) ( 20 214 34 252 ) ",
    "( 254 129 397 224 ) Done. ",
    "video 1/1 (3/742) ( 246 152 341 238 ) ",
    "( 248 202 277 247 ) ",
    "( 20 214 34 252 ) ",
    "( 255 129 396 224 )  Done. ",
    "video 1/1 (4/742) ( 248 202 277 247 ) ",
    "( 245 152 341 238 ) ",
    "( 20 214 34 252 ) ",
    "( 255 129 396 224 )  Done. ",
    "video 1/1 (5/742) ( 17 213 36 251 ) ",
    "( 246 153 339 238 ) ",
    "( 252 203 278 247 ) ",
    "( 254 129 398 223 )  Done."
]
required_data = [f"{sentence.strip()} Done." for sentence in ''.join(data).split("Done.") if sentence.strip()]
```

## Output

[image]